# How can we store every Object passed through a on-click event in an array after each time the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to Pass a button in a map function,
And then trying to Obtain all the values in an array which I get after every on-click event function.
The map function looks like this

```
  {Data.map((d, i) => {
      return (
       <div key={i} >
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td className="date">{d.Date}</td>
    <td className="time">{d.Time}</td>
    <td className="availability" >{d.Availabilty}</td>
    <td><button value={JSON.stringify(d)} onClick={(e)=>{
      decNum(e);
      }}>Book Now</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</div>
      )
})}
```

The onclick function goes like this

```
const decNum=(e)=>{
  var i =0
    cartData[i] = e.target.value
    i = i+1
    console.log(cartData)
    console.log( e.target.value)
  }
```

I am getting the value for the particular button that i am clicking on and nothing else.
And I want to get all the previous data That I have clicked on before.

thanks in advance

for reference The data Passes in the map function goes like this

```
const Data =[
    {
   "Date":"Thu Jul 06 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"9 seats available",
  
  },
  {
   "Date":"Fri Jul 07 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"7 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Sat Jul 08 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"10 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Sun Jul 09 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"3 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Mon Jul 10 2021" ,
   "Time": "01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"14 seats available",
  },
  
  {
   "Date":"Wed Jul 12 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty": "12 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Thu Jul 13 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty": "15 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Fri Jul 14 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"8 seats available",
  },
  {
   "Date":"Sat Jul 15 2021" ,
   "Time":"01:00 PM PST -03:00 PM PST",
   "Availabilty":"1 seats available"
  } 
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data structure makes more sense as key/value pairs like

```
{datetime: numSeats}
```

Add a data attribute to the button element to store the count (in case you wan to access it directly) and then populate your object.

```
const Cart = (props) => {
    const cartData = {}

    const decNum=(e)=>{
      let n = +e.target.dataset.count +1; // get the current number from the dataset, inc by 1
      cartData[e.target.value] = n; // assign the value to your obj
      e.target.dataset.count = n; // put the new value back into the dataset
    }

    .....

    {Data.map((d, i) => {
          return (
           <div key={i} >
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td className="date">{d.Date}</td>
        <td className="time">{d.Time}</td>
        <td className="availability" >{d.Availabilty}</td>
        <td><button value={JSON.stringify(d)} 
              data-count='0' onClick={(e)=> { decNum(e); }}>
                 Book Now
             </button></td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>
    </div>
          )
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 var i =0
    cartData[i] = e.target.value
    i = i+1
}
```

This does `carData[0] = 'abcd'` every time the function is called.
Your `i` should be outside the scope of this function. You can even do something like `carData.push(e.target.value)`. That would be ideal, you will not run into reference errors too.

All this assumes, your carData is defined as an error initially and does not reset itself on every click.